# How can I make all columns have same width with tabularX?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to make a table that has equal column widths. When I write text I want the text to go vertically, however I can't seem to make my last column behave as the other columns using tabularx package.
Here the code:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}[input-decimal-markers=.]
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{table}[t]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.2\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} 
\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXXXs{}} 
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Study}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Design}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Data source}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Algorithms used }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Findings}&\multicolumn{1}{r}{Limitations}\\
    \midrule
    Malone et al. (2007)25
    Cross-sectional
    study &Test of a really long description which should itself span many rows, in fact occupying much space, hopefully, causing it to span a couple of normal rows &test123?&0.3928&Test of a really long description which should itself span many rows, in fact occupying much spac?& test \\
    Age&Test of a really long description which should itself span many rows, in fact occupying much space, hopefully, causing it to span a couple of normal rows & 49.16&15.82&test&test\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Here a picture of the table:
[image]

Why am I not able to make my last column use the X parameter from tabularx, but constrained to s? Could anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the sixth and final column to have the same width as the first five columns, change its type from `s` to `X`:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXXXX@{}}    
...
\end{tabularx}
```